# where to place cancel button on form

Tags: html, forms, button

Does anyone know the correct place of the cancel button in a form?
Does it have to be on the left of the submit button or on the right?

Answer (score 1):

This article by Jeff may be of interest http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html

It's not specific to the Cancel button but still a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Most people read left to right, so it's normal to have OK on the left. At least, this is the Windows convention. OS X does it the other way around, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Jakob Nielsen is widely considered an expert on usability and user interface design.  He gives his opinion in this article:
"[OK–Cancel or Cancel–OK?](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ok-cancel.html)".

The summary of his answer is: It's actually not an important UI issue, but if you are designing for Windows, put OK first; on Mac, put OK last; on the web, put OK first unless the majority of your users are not using Windows (but see also this article on [*Reset* and *Cancel* Buttons](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000416.html) for the web).